# How to update JLabel that stores an image

Tags: java, forms, image, swing

I'm trying to download certain pictures via JButton.

The form starts, there is a JTextBox where I write the ID, so the button should get the photo, but I don't really know how to update the JLabel I'm using to store and show the image.

I put a default URL, so when it starts is goint to show always the same picture.

Using JLabel is the best way to store and show an image?

Is it possible to resize the photo?

Thanks

---

```
package fotoMatricula;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class FotoMatricula {

private JFrame frame;
private JTextField textField;
private String foto;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                FotoMatricula window = new FotoMatricula();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public FotoMatricula() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
public void initialize() {
    Image image = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://charal.unacar.mx/fotos/103522.jpg");
        image = ImageIO.read(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 391, 396);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblIntroduceTuMatrcula = new JLabel("Introduce tu matr\u00EDcula");
    lblIntroduceTuMatrcula.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
    lblIntroduceTuMatrcula.setBounds(104, 11, 174, 24);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblIntroduceTuMatrcula);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(139, 46, 94, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(89, 77, 202, 189);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);


    JButton btnBuscar = new JButton("Buscar");
    btnBuscar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            foto = textField.getText();
            lblNewLabel.setText(foto);
        }
    });
    btnBuscar.setBounds(139, 303, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnBuscar);
    }
}
```

Comment: To change the Icon of a JLabel you can use the `setIcon(...)` method of the label.

Comment: I actually tried that like 10 mins ago, when I click the button the default image disappears and that's it, doesn't load the new image :( 
I put a System.out.println just to check if the URL is correct, and it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it, as you did trough initialisation... 
Try this in your actionListener:

```
 try
 {
     URL url2 = new URL (textField.getText());
     lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(url2)));
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {

 }
```

Comment: I actually solved it like 10 mins ago! Using exactly what you wrote, thanks for reply!

I also added this to resize the image new ImageIcon(imagen.getScaledInstance(324, 455, imagen.SCALE_SMOOTH)));

Comment: @ David: No problem! Consider accepting this answer, because it solves your problem (even if you got it on your own). It might help others..